# Optimize a function that has many outputs with python scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I've been searching a little in the web and I did not found any solution to this question, so I decided to formally ask here.

I have a function that has multiple outputs:

```
f(input1,input2,... ,inputn) = output1,ouput2,output3
```

My wish is to minimize `output1` constraining other outputs, for instance:

```
output2 >= 0 and output3 <= 7   (*constraints*)
```

My idea was to have the following program structure:

```
def function(input1,input2,...,inputn):
    #very secret part of code
    return(output1,ouput2,output3)

inputs=[1,31,22]
_res = optimize.minimize(function, inputs,  method='nelder-mead', 
options=options,*constraints*)
```

Now I believe that the answer should be in the documentation of the Scipy [`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function.

The fact is that, from what I've understood, I can only constrain my function inputs and not some of the outputs of my function. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of optimization with constraint:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(xy):
    x, y = xy 
    return x**2 + y**2

def constraint1(xy):
    x, y = xy 
    return x-1

def constraint2(xy):
    x, y = xy 
    return y-2

constraints = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2})

xy_start = [0, 0]
res = minimize(f, xy_start, method='SLSQP', constraints=constraints)
```

which gives:

```
     fun: 4.999999999999997
     jac: array([2., 4.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 13
     nit: 3
    njev: 3
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([1., 2.])
```

The idea is that your function you want to minimize is well scalar: the returned value have to be only `output1`. Additional functions have to be added in order to define each constraint: `constraint1(inputs)->output2`, `constraint2(inputs)->output3`... etc

Maybe you could separate the 'very secret part' of your code into different functions, which will be used both by the objective function and by the constraints functions